# How much did Peter Pettigrew learn about Harry as Scabbers, and did he ever relay all this personal information to Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, death-eaters

Whilst reading the first three books, and especially PoA, *I kept wondering whether it's known how much Pettigrew learned about Harry, Ron and Hermione whilst in Animagus form; i.e. as Scabbers*.

How valuable did his time as Ron's pet rat turn out to be when it came to strategic or personal information? *How much did/could/would he tell Voldemort* - assuming the latter cared, or even trusted or respected the former enough to value their information?

Answer (score 6):

## Unclear -  it’s possible he gave the Dark Lord information on them.

Though it’s not clear how much about Wormtail told the Dark Lord about Harry, Ron, and Hermione, since it isn’t mentioned that he gave the Dark Lord any information on the three of them specifically, he likely did share some information with the Dark Lord in general. Also, Wormtail did share at least some information that he learned while in disguise as Ron’s pet. He told the Dark Lord what Macnair, one of the Death Eaters, was doing in the Dark Lord’s absence, and it was for sure Wormtail who did, as the Dark Lord attributes his knowledge of it to him.

> “Macnair … destroying dangerous beasts for the Ministry of Magic now, Wormtail tells me? You shall have better victims than that soon, Macnair. Lord Voldemort will provide …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33 (The Death Eaters)*</sup></sub>

Wormtail would’ve learned this in disguise as Scabbers, as Scabbers is there in Hagrid’s hut when Macnair shows up as the Ministry’s executioner when Buckbeak was sentenced to execution.

> “Behind them came the feeble old Committee member and the executioner, Macnair.
>
> ‘Yeh gotta go,’ said Hagrid. Every inch of him was trembling. ‘They mustn’ find yeh here … go on, now …’
>
> Ron stuffed Scabbers into his pocket and Hermione picked up the Cloak.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 16 (Professor Trelawney’s Prediction)*</sup></sub>

Wormtail also likely gave the Dark Lord other possibly useful information he had, as he seems to have told the Dark Lord that Sirius was an Animagus, as Sirius suspected he would.

> “Because the Ministry of Magic’s still after me, and Voldemort will know all about me being an Animagus by now, Wormtail will have told him, so my big disguise is useless.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 5 (The Order of the Phoenix)*</sup></sub>

Wormtail most likely did tell the Dark Lord, and the Dark Lord seems to have trusted the information, as Bellatrix also knows that Sirius is an Animagus, and Lucius also seems to know, so it’s likely the Dark Lord informed the Death Eaters as well.

> “Master, I am sorry, I knew not, I was fighting the Animagus Black!’ sobbed Bellatrix, flinging herself down at Voldemort’s feet as he paced slowly nearer.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 36 (The Only One He Ever Feared)*</sup></sub>

The Dark Lord does seem well-informed on Harry, like knowing how he likes to play the hero - it’s possible he got some of his information from Wormtail. He did have a mental link with Harry, but that isn’t necessarily how he knows so much about him.

> “Oh, you don’t know Potter as I do, Bellatrix,’ said Malfoy softly. ‘He has a great weakness for heroics; the Dark Lord understands this about him.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 35 (Beyond the Veil)*</sup></sub>

Wormtail would’ve been able to gather information in Animagus form and remember it as a human, since Rita Skeeter collected stories as a beetle to write when she turned back.

> “Harry looked, and saw that she was quite right. He also remembered something. ‘There was a beetle on the statue the night we heard Hagrid telling Madame Maxime about his mum!’
>
> ‘Exactly,’ said Hermione. ‘And Viktor pulled a beetle out of my hair after we’d had our conversation by the lake. And unless I’m very much mistaken, Rita was perched on the window-sill of the Divination class the day your scar hurt. She’s been buzzing around for stories all year.’
>
> ‘When we saw Malfoy under that tree …’ said Ron slowly.’
>
> ‘He was talking to her, in his hand,’ said Hermione.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 37 (The Beginning)*</sup></sub>

So it is possible that Wormtail also shared information he learned while in Animagus form about Harry, Ron, and Hermione with the Dark Lord as well.

Answer (score 2):

### He probably did share what he had learned

I don't think there is ever an explicit mention of Peter Pettigrew telling Voldemort information he picked up about Harry, but it seems likely that he would have, based on several factors.

### He shared other information

We know that he told Voldemort other information that he had picked up over the years of Voldemort's exile. When Voldemort rebukes the Death Eaters in the graveyard at the end of *Goblet of Fire* he says:

> "Macnair... destroying dangerous beasts for the Ministry of Magic now,
>   Wormtail tells me.

### He didn't care about Harry

One might suppose that Pettigrew would refrain from giving Voldemort information in order to help Harry, but Pettigrew himself tells Voldemort in the beginning of *Goblet of Fire* that he does not care about Harry:

> "My Lord, I do not say this out of concern for the boy!" said
>   Wormtail, his voice rising squeakily. "The boy is nothing to me,
>   nothing at all!

While this is something that one would say even if it wasn't true, and indeed Voldemort accuses him of lying in that very scene, I don't see evidence that he was lying about that specific point.

### He could use the extra value it would give him

Additionally, Pettigrew needed every possible way to curry favor with Voldemort. Throughout the time that he attended Voldemort, Voldemort repeatedly mocked his incompetence and wavering loyalty. If Pettigrew had any valuable information it would certainly add to his usefulness if he shared it with Voldemort. We know, for instance, that Voldemort was particularly pleased with all the information Snape was able to provide him from his years in Hogwarts, as Snape informs Bellatrix in the begining of *Half-Blood Prince*:

> "Hardly," said Snape "although the Dark Lord is pleased that I never
>   deserted my post: I had sixteen years of information on Dumbledore to
>   give him when he returned, a rather more useful welcome-back present
>   than endless reminiscences of how unpleasant Azkaban is..."

### Sirius assumed that he had divulged information

Additionally, we know that Sirius assumed that Pettigrew had in fact told Voldemort about Sirius's animagus form, as Sirius tells Harry in the beginning of *Order of the Phoenix*:

> "Because the Ministry of Magic's still after me, and Voldemort will
>   know all about me being an animagus by now, Wormtail will have told
>   him, so my big disguise is useless.

We also know from later in *Order of the Phoenix* when Sirius and Snape got into an argument over Christmas that Lucius Malfoy recognized Sirius's dog form, so that likely confirms that Pettigrew did share the information:

> “Speaking of dogs,” said Snape softly, “did you know that Lucius
>   Malfoy recognized you last time you risked a little jaunt outside?
>   Clever idea, Black, getting yourself seen on a safe station platform...
>   gave you a cast-iron excuse not to leave your hideyhole in future,
>   didn’t it?”

We can assume that if Pettigrew told Voldemort about Sirius, he probably also told him about Harry as well.

### There probably wasn't much to tell

Even assuming Pettigrew did share the information he had picked up, it probably wasn't very much. Harry didn't have very many secrets worth telling. Most things about him (e.g. that he was good at flying, or who his friends were) were probably well known, and most other information would probably not be very useful. Pettigrew might have known a few things, such as that Harry had an Invisibilty Cloak and the Marauders Map, but even that would be of limited use to Voldemort. The one time that we know that Voldemort needed personal information about Harry, Pettigrew was apparently unable to provide it and Voldemort got it from Kreacher instead, as Dumbledore told Harry after the battle at the Ministry in *Order of the Phoenix:

> “Oh yes,” said Dumbledore. “You see, Kreacher was not able to betray
>   us totally. He is not Secret-Keeper for the Order, he could not give
>   the Malfoys our whereabouts or tell them any of the Order’s
>   confidential plans that he had been forbidden to reveal. He was bound
>   by the enchantments of his kind, which is to say that he could not
>   disobey a direct order from his master, Sirius. But he gave Narcissa
>   information of the sort that is very valuable to Voldemort, yet must
>   have seemed much too trivial for Sirius to think of banning him from
>   repeating it.”
>
> “Like what?” said Harry.
>
> “Like the fact that the person Sirius cared most about in the world
>   was you,” said Dumbledore quietly. “Like the fact that you were coming
>   to regard Sirius as a mixture of father and brother. Voldemort knew
>   already, of course, that Sirius was in the Order, that you knew where
>   he was — but Kreacher’s information made him realize that the one
>   person whom you would go to any lengths to rescue was Sirius Black.”

Indeed, this information, like most of the important things about Harry that pertained to Voldemort, was not even known to Harry at the time that Pettigrew was impersonating Scabbers.

Comment: Good answer! I only would not agree with the part where Wormtail doesn't care about Harry. I feel like the exact quote you provide there is in fact the first sign of Pettigrew feeling obliged for Harry saving his life - exactly what Dumbledore predicted. It's a strange thing to mention his possible concern for the boy at all - he already proven to be able to betray even his closest friends - so it feels more like he says something that is already on his mind.

Comment: @ShanaTar Could be. But he does say it in response to Voldemort's veiled accusation, so it would make sense for him to bring it up if he thought that's what Voldemort was accusing him of. Then again, that thought itself might be a psychological projection of what he is actually feeling.